File Descriptor sharing between processes
My goal is to open the device in one process and then close it in another (not fork).
I don't want to use UNIX socket. I found that starting kernel 5.6 there are two new syscalls: syscall(SYS_pidfd_open, pid, flags) and syscall(SYS_pidfd_getfd, pidfd, 0, 0).
I tried simple code to check this solution.
open_device.c:
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <errno.h>

#define pidfd_open(pid, flags) syscall(SYS_pidfd_open, pid, flags)

int main() {
    // Open the device
    int fd = open("/dev/null", O_RDWR);
    if (fd == -1) {
        perror("open");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    printf("File descriptor for /dev/null: %d\n", fd);

    // Get the current process ID
    pid_t pid = getpid();

    // Obtain a pidfd for this process
    int pidfd = pidfd_open(pid, 0);
    if (pidfd == -1) {
        perror("pidfd_open");
        close(fd);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    printf("Generated pidfd: %d\n", pidfd);

    // Write pidfd to a file
    FILE *pidfd_file = fopen("pidfd.txt", "w");
    if (pidfd_file == NULL) {
        perror("fopen");
        close(fd);
        close(pidfd);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    fprintf(pidfd_file, "%d\n", pidfd);
    fclose(pidfd_file);

    // Keep the process alive for testing
    while (1) {
        sleep(10);
    }

    // Clean up
    close(fd);
    close(pidfd);

    return 0;
}

close_device.c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>
#include <errno.h>

#ifndef SYS_pidfd_getfd
#define SYS_pidfd_getfd 438  // Replace with the correct syscall number for your architecture
#endif

int main() {
    // Read the pidfd from the file
    FILE *pidfd_file = fopen("pidfd.txt", "r");
    if (pidfd_file == NULL) {
        perror("fopen");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    int pidfd;
    if (fscanf(pidfd_file, "%d", &pidfd) != 1) {
        perror("fscanf");
        fclose(pidfd_file);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    fclose(pidfd_file);

    printf("Read pidfd: %d\n", pidfd);

    // Retrieve the file descriptor from the first process
    int target_fd = syscall(SYS_pidfd_getfd, pidfd, 0, 0);
    if (target_fd == -1) {
        perror("pidfd_getfd");
        close(pidfd);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    printf("Successfully retrieved fd: %d\n", target_fd);

    // Perform the close operation
    if (close(target_fd) == -1) {
        perror("close");
        close(pidfd);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    printf("Device successfully closed.\n");

    close(pidfd);
    return 0;
} 

The problem is that I receive error Bad file descriptor for pidfd_getfd.
Where can be an issue?

I haven't used these APIs before but the syscall(SYS_pidfd_getfd, ... invocation looks a bit odd.  According to the documentation the second parameter should be the pid of the opening process and the third parameter the target fd in that process (unless I've misread).  That's not what you have.

@G.M.  Read the documentation again.  OP is using it correctly.

@stark OK, I still don't quite follow but I'll happily defer to others :-)

@stark No, it's not used correctly in OPs code as G.M. pointed out.  pidfd should be the PID file descriptor, not the file file descriptor that you want to duplicate.

You are using the wrong arguments for SYS_pidfd_getfd. pidfd should be a PID descriptor, int pidfd = pidfd_open(remote_pid, 0);, where remote_pid is the process ID of the process which you want to obtain a duplicate file descriptor from.
You could just write the PID of the opening process down to the same file and then in close_device.c you read that and then call pidfd_open:
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>

#ifndef SYS_pidfd_getfd
#    define SYS_pidfd_getfd \
        438 // Replace with the correct syscall number for your architecture
#endif

#define pidfd_open(pid, flags) syscall(SYS_pidfd_open, pid, flags)

int main(void) {
    // Read the pidfd from the file
    FILE* pidfd_file = fopen("pidfd.txt", "r");
    if(pidfd_file == NULL) {
        perror("fopen");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    pid_t remote_pid;
    int remote_fd;
    // read both pid and the descriptor from the file:
    // Note: %d may not be appropriate for `pid_t`
    if(fscanf(pidfd_file, "%d %d", &remote_pid, &remote_fd) != 2) {
        perror("fscanf");
        fclose(pidfd_file);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    fclose(pidfd_file);
    printf("Read pid:%d  remote_fd: %d\n", remote_pid, remote_fd);

    // now get the pidfd for the remote process:
    int pidfd = pidfd_open(remote_pid, 0);
    if(pidfd == -1) {
        perror("pidfd_open");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    // Now you can retrieve the file descriptor from the remote process
    int target_fd = syscall(SYS_pidfd_getfd, pidfd, remote_fd, 0);
    if(target_fd == -1) {
        perror("pidfd_getfd");
        close(pidfd);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    printf("Successfully retrieved fd: %d\n", target_fd);

    // Perform the close operation
    if(close(target_fd) == -1) {
        perror("close");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    printf("Device successfully closed.\n");
}


Thank you for your help! Now I get following error:
pidfd_getfd: Operation not permitted```

Well, the kernel has told you.... have you read the documentation associated to those system calls?  (a read of the last paragraph on my answer will probably explain why you receive this error)

@Droll80 The process must have permission to duplicate the other process' file descriptor. Are you running both processes as the same user? "Permission to duplicate another process's file descriptor is  governed by a ptrace access mode PTRACE_MODE_ATTACH_REALCREDS check (see ptrace(2))."
